# Binary Search Tree deletion

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am a beginner in programming and currently learning about bst. I have found several functions which delete bst, but they seemed to me overcomplexed. So i am interested if my own code cleans all the memory, every pointer and value of a binary search tree.

```
void deletebst (Node*& node)
{
if (node!=NULL)
{
deletebst (node->ldes); //deletes a left descendant recursively
deletebst (node->rdes); //same but with the right one
delete node; //deletes the value which a pointer 'node' points to
node=NULL; //sets a pointer 'node' to NULL, so deletes a pointer itself
}
}
```

Comment: `sets a pointer 'node' to NULL, so deletes a pointer itself`. This makes no sense. You didn't delete anything by setting it to `NULL`.

Comment: OK, I see. So this action isn't needed at all? I think i have seen somewhere that we need to set a pointer to NULL after it has ended its 'mission'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments section, there's no need to set node = NULL, after it's been deleted. The rest of the code is fine. Cheers!